# Purpose and maintenance of aluminum rectangles on the clothes dryer drum?

Tags: repair, dryer

What is the purpose of the three aluminum rectangle sheets glued to the exterior of a clothes dryer drum?

And, what would be the proper maintenance/repair for where the aluminum is starting to peel and lint is stuck onto the original adhesive side (where peeling)? For example,

- replace it? (can't find a part number. )
- re-glue? (which adhesive? & what to do with the lint on the existing adhesive?)
- remove and re-glue? (much for something mostly still sticking OK)
- fabricate a new piece (some clean new aluminum sheet. still which adhesive would be appropriate?)
- place some (aluminum) tape on the loose ends?
- just remove it altogether? (why is part needed?)

The Whirlpool Duet dryer drum pictured below shows one of the aluminum retangle starting to peel.

[image: Dryer Drum]

This `Drum Assembly W10545923` is used by
[Whirlpool](https://www.whirlpoolparts.com/PartDetail/Drum-Assembly/W10545923/3021660), Kenmore,
[Maytag](https://www.maytagreplacementparts.com/PartDetail/Drum-Assembly/W10545923/3021660),
[Amana](https://www.amanaparts.com/PartDetail/Drum-Assembly/W10545923/3021660),
and Admiral. However, I can not find the alumimun piece as a part number separate from the drum.

---

**Additional Information**

*Acoustic Effect*

No additional info.

*Dynamic Balance*

The three rectangles are symmetrically placed as if the intent is to not affect the balance.

*Magnetic Induction Brake or Damper*

The side metal rectangles appear darker in the photos. Their appearance is like galvanize zinc.

A photo is added below which better shows that the side rectangle and drum rectangle are not aligned.

The darker metal rectangles glued to the side panels are not magnetized base on steel washer test. (Washer was checked with magnet.)

*Rotation RPM Sensor Component*

I did not find any complementary RPM or position sensing electrics relative to the drum rectangles.

*Static Electricity*

If this is the case, would one edge of the rectangle be intentionly "flapping" to touch (scrape along) the side? If yes, the *rotation trailing* edge "flap" is by design, then maintence/repair would only require that *rotation leading* edge be secured. If no, then both edges would need to be somehow secured.

[image: Drum to Side View]

Comment: it may have something to do with static electricity management ... i cannot think of any other reason for it ... the other though is some anti resonance function, but the sheet appears to be too flimsy

Comment: reflective rotational sensor measuring the speed of the drum

Comment: I think @Ruskes might have it.  There are black rectangles on the sides that seem to match.  Do not know why the RPM would matter, but I don't have one with all the fancy electronics on it.

Comment: Could be a magnetic induction brake or damper to load the drum and slow it down when it is lightly loaded. If so, I would expect the black rectangle to be magnetized. See if normal steel washers are attracted to the black rectangle. Aluminum is not attracted to a magnet, but a moving piece of aluminum in a magnetic field resists motion. Aluminum dampers were common in the triple beam balances used in chemistry labs in the 1960s and later.

Comment: Don't remove it. Check with the mfgr for info. Glue the loose part back with appropriate glue. Might be anti-static.

Comment: @Ruskes I thought of a rotation sensor also, but the sheets are too large, and only one would be required ... manufacturers do not spend money frivolously

Comment: Based on the comments I've added some additional findings to the question.

Comment: I think the right answer really is "ask the manufacturer these questions." It's not a common feature, so it's something specific to this model and/or brand.

Comment: If they're thicker than foil, i.e., have a mastic backing. at least one purpose is to reduce noise -- as you state, "acoustic effect". They might have another function, as well, but if they're just peeling  bit in the corner, I'd stick back just that corner using a flexible, non-flammable adhesive. "Liquid nails" and similar adhesives should be fine, after flammable solvent has evaporated (a few hours).

Comment: If the concern is them falling off, or coming loose and flapping against part of the cabinet, I'd just tape the ends down with some Nashua 324A tape.

Answer (score 0):

It's to dampen the sound of things hitting the inside of the drum. You can remove it and replace it with "Protecto Wrap" which can be bought at most big box stores for < 20 bucks. It's located in the building materials/window area.